# PHP queue file implementation

Tags: php, file, unix, memory, queue

For a project I was working on I need a queue which will be too large to hold in normal memory.  I had been implementing it as a simple file where it would read the whole file take the first few (~100) lines, process them, then write back the updated queue with new instructions added and the old ones removed.  However, since the queue became too large to hold in memory like this I need something different.  Preferably someone can tell me a way to peel off just the first few lines of a file without having to look at the rest of the data.  I had thought about using a database (MySQL probably with sorted insert timestamps) but I would heavily prefer to do it without for load and bandwidth reasons (several servers would have to all be sending and receiving a lot of data from the DB).  The language I'm working in is PHP but really this question is more about unix files I suppose.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*several servers would have to all be sending and receiving a lot of data from the DB*" - This is exactly what database servers are designed (and optimized) to do.

Comment: I know that the database could handle it but what I am more concerned about is the bandwidth involved of having this process constantly running and shooting data between all my servers... The MySQL way is my last resort but I would really prefer if someone knows a way to update the file to remove the first few lines without having to look at all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucking out the first line of a file is pretty trivial (`fopen()` followed by an `fgets()`). Re-writing the file to remove completed jobs would be very painful, especially if you've got multiple concurrent servers working off the same queue file.

One alternative would be to use a seperate file for each job. If you have some concurrency-safe method of generating an incrementing ID for these files, then it'd be a simple matter of picking out the file with the lowest id for the oldest job, and generating a new id for each new job. You'd have to figure out some file locking, though, to keep two+ servers grabbing the same file at the same time, however.

Comment: I actually am using locking -- what I really need is some way to move the pointer which signifies the start of the file down over the lines that have already been executed.

Comment: you could use `ftell()` to get the position of the 'start here' marker in the queue file, and store that in a seperate file. lock/read/update/write/unlock on a small ~10byte file would be fairly quick, and let you scroll directly to the relevant spot in the queue with ease.

Comment: ok that sounds more like what I am looking for... the actual size of the queue file would continue to grow though so I would have to at some point empty it out one memory sized chunk at a time...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems while I was working on [enqueue/fs](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/transport/filesystem.md) transport. I failed to modify a small portion at the begging of the file without copying it to the memory and saving back. Instead, but that's possible to do that with the end of the file. You can read a portion and then truncate it. That's not really a queue but a stack. So if you rely on message ordering this would not be a solution.  In my case, I lock the file when the file has been read from the file, the lock is released.

This is how you could write messages to a queue file:

```
<?php
$rawMessage = 'this your message to put to the queue as a string';

$queueFile = fopen('/path/to/queue/file', '+a');

// here it may add some spaces so the message length is multiples of modular.
// that make it easier to read messages from a file.

// lock file

$rawMessage = str_repeat(' ', 64 - (strlen($rawMessage) % 64)).$rawMessage;
fwrite($queueFile, $rawMessage);

// release lock
```

This is how you could read messages from a queue file:

```
<?php

$queueFile = fopen('/path/to/queue/file', '+c');

// lock file

$frame = readFrame($file, 1);
ftruncate($file, fstat($file)['size'] - strlen($frame));
rewind($file);
$rawMessage = substr(trim($frame), 1);

// release lock


function readFrame($file, $frameNumber)
{
    $frameSize = 64;
    $offset = $frameNumber * $frameSize;
    fseek($file, -$offset, SEEK_END);
    $frame = fread($file, $frameSize);
    if ('' == $frame) {
        return '';
    }
    if (false !== strpos($frame, '|{')) {
        return $frame;
    }
    return readFrame($file, $frameNumber + 1).$frame;
}
```

For the locking I'd suggest using [Symfony LockHandler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/lock_handler.html) or simply take enqueue/fs.